# Why a decimal value from MySQL is converted into/shown as integer?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, decimal

My database includes a table named `Quotations`. This table has a column named `Cost` with a datatype *decimal (10, 2)*. Values are saved/updated as per my expectation inside the column just like (`25.75`, `4.35`, `10.38` etc).

Problem is that whenever I use `{{ $quotation->cost }}` to display the information, all the *decimals* are printed as *integers* like (`25`, `4`, `10`). But if I check it with `{{ dd($quotation) }}`, it shows all the exact decimal values like (`25.75`, `4.35`, `10.38` etc).

I shall appreciate it if someone points out the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Does `protected $casts => ['cost' => 'float']` not work?

Comment: Consider storing your cost / price variables using the [minor currency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37107182/3578036) rather than storing the decimals. In short, store `2575`, instead of `25.75`, then setting up a `getCostAttribute` that returns the `cost / 100`.

Comment: did you try this? ```<?php echo $quotation->cost; ?>``` or ```{!! $quotation->cost !!}```

Comment: Thanks @JustCarty. ```protected $casts => ['cost' => 'float']``` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I thank everybody for your timely responses.

Before the solution, I actually was ignoring `protected $casts = [ 'cost' => 'integer' ]`. Replacing `integer` to `float` resolved my issue.

Comment: Glad my comment helped solve this, you can also mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use {!! $quotation->cost !!}

Answer (score 0):

Use number_format function while displaying the decimal value

Comment: Already tried but the output is like 25.00, 4.00, 10.00 instead of 25.75, 4.35, 10.38

Comment: Can you share your code? Model, Migration and the controller or view where you are trying to display these values?